# what is manage-bde in windows 7 professional?

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

Many of my colleagues say Windows 7 professional has no Bitlocker. If I keep using Windows 7, I should buy a Windows 7 Enterprise.

But, why I can run the command `manage-bde`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Why I can run the command `manage-bde`?

`manage-bde` can be used on all version of Windows 7. So you can use it on Windows 7 Professional to **unlock encrypted removable drives**.

---

#### Manage-bde

> Applies To: Windows 7, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows
>   Server 2012, Windows 8
>
> `manage-bde` is used to turn on or turn off BitLocker, specify unlock
>   mechanisms, update recovery methods, and unlock BitLocker-protected
>   data drives.

Source [Manage-bde](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829849(v=ws.11).aspx)

---

#### BitLocker Drive Encryption in Windows 7: Frequently Asked Questions

> **What versions of Windows 7 include BitLocker? Can I use BitLocker on a Windows XP–based computer?**
>
> BitLocker is available in Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 7 Enterprise. **However, you can unlock encrypted removable drives on any version of Windows 7**. BitLocker is not available in Windows XP, but you can use the BitLocker To Go Reader to view content on BitLocker-protected removable drives from a computer running Windows XP.

Source [BitLocker Drive Encryption in Windows 7: Frequently Asked Questions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449438(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_Vista)